# Rotation in html5 without css3

Tags: html, rotation

How can we implement rotation of a html element without css3.?

It is very easy to use CSS3 animation like

```
{
   Rotation-point: 50% 50%;
  Rotation: 180deg;
}
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear as to why you don't want to use CSS. Is it because of browser support issues, or because you want to control it in a script? Or some other reason? The best answer may vary depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, so it would help if you give more info than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I come across jquery rotate which is a solution for rotation even in IE8 which doesn't support CSS3

Please refer link for details

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#elementId').css({'transform':'rotate(45deg)',
                 '-moz-transform':'rotate(45deg)',
                 '-webkit-transform':'rotate(45deg)',
                 '-o-transform':'rotate(45deg)',
                 '-ms-transform':'rotate(45deg)'});
```

This using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to rotate elements; just set the rotation style:

```
element.style.transform='rotate(45deg)';
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6CJpK/

But this is still using CSS, albeit controlled by Javascript.

This will obviously only work in modern browsers that support the `transform` style. For older browsers you will need a polyfill of some sort, or a library like jQuery.

But this is *still* using CSS under the hood.

If you really want a solution that goes nowhere near CSS, then you'll need to resort to drawing graphics using SVG or Canvas, and using the built-in rotation functions in those APIs.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to use CSS3 then you can prefer Jquery.

Jquery is the most effective one and it reduces out code and time.